# populate dropdown list based on count in db

Tags: laravel

> I want to populate a dropdownlist based on db value.If my db column value is 45 then i want a dropdown list like
> select values as 1,2,3,4.......................till 45.

```
<div class="form-group">
<select name="labCat" id="lab" class="form-control input-lg dynamic" data-dependent="labSubCat">
<option value="">Select ward</option>
    @foreach($ward as $lb)
        <option value="{{$lb->ward_id}}">{{$lb->ward_id}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: It's not clear from your post what you are trying to accomplish. This code example does not appear to be jQuery. Please provide a  Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: i dont have any idea to populate dropdownlist.this is my requirment,My db has value 45 and a need a dropdownlist with 45 select items

Comment: You need to do this using jquery ? But why, you can simply do that using your server-side code..? as you are already using loop?

Comment: how i do this.i dont have any idea

Comment: Is this laravel ? Please add relevant tag as well.

Comment: yeah i added.please find me a solution

Comment: Hi you can use `{{ $loop->iteration }}` so that it start from 1 and ends when the loop reached to end.For more info refer [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#loops,)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222998/discussion-between-buddingdeveloper-and-swati).

Comment: does $ward is the table whose columns you want to show in dropdown ?

Comment: can you please provide dd($ward) array... and controller code.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use for loop with its limit <= your DB count.

```
<select name="labCat" id="lab" class="form-control input-lg dynamic" data-dependent="labSubCat">
<option value="">Select ward</option>
    @for ($i = 0; $i <= (int)$ward; $i++)
          <option value="{{$i}}">{{$i}}</option>
    @endfor
</select>
```